# Saving in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method in my `country.rb` where I defined a new method.

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states, :dependent => :destroy

  after_save :count_total_states

  def count_total_states
    self.duration = State.count(:conditions => { :country_id => self.id })
    Country.save!(:duration => self.duration)
  end
end
```

I got the `self.duration` result I wanted. But when I ran it, it said

`undefined method 'save!' for #<Class:0x111170d10>`

I want it to count number of states belong to the country everytime a new state is created. Please advise what to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `update_column` instead. It skips the callbacks and validations. Here are the docs on [update_column](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column).

Also, `states.count` already gives you the query to find the states by country. The `has_many :states` allows you to do this.

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states, :dependent => :destroy

  after_save :count_total_states

  def count_total_states
    update_column(:duration, states.count)
  end
end
```

Comment: Reason why I need to do it `after_save` is because I want to make sure the new State is saved, before I do a count. If I do a count before save, it doesn't include the new state.

Comment: Updated my answer once again to fix your problem. This does what you want.

Comment: Thanks. It works. May I know why it must be `update_column` not `update_attribute`?

Comment: Because `update_attribute` triggers the callbacks e.g. `before_save`, `after_save`, `before_destroy`, etc. `update_column` just writes to the database and nothing else. 


I still recommend you still use `update_attribute` and `update_attributes` when possible. Only use `update_column` in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

It must be like this:

```
def count_total_states
    duration = State.count(:conditions => { :country_id => self.id })
    self.save!(:duration => duration)
end
```

Comment: I actually tried that. But I got ruby memory leak, that sucked up all my free ram and not responding.

Comment: That's because its causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of mistakes here.

1. save! is an instance method so Country.save! wont work (Country is a class).
2. You're calling save! in a method which is being triggered by a after_save callback which will cause an infinite loop.

A better solution would be:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states, :dependent => :destroy

  after_create :count_total_states

  def count_total_states
    self.duration = State.count(:conditions => { :country_id =>    self.id })
    self.save        
  end
end
```

Of course another advantage with using a before_save callback in this scenario is you're saving the additional sql (UPDATE ...) that would have otherwise happened with an after_save.

**EDIT**

```
I want it to count number of states belong to the country everytime a new state is created.
```

In your scenario, given the above statement and the comment below you will have to use the after_create method.

Comment: Reason why I need to do it `after_save` is because I want to make sure the new State is saved, before I do a count. If I do a count before save, it doesn't include the new state.

Comment: You can't use after_save in your scenario because as I said, it would cause an infinite loop. I've updated my answer. If you don't want to use before_save use after_create.

Comment: So can I use `after_create :count_total_states` and `after_update :count_total_states` together because an update will actually allow new states to be added? Actually it is a nested model. I just simplify it in my question.